How to use mathematical notation to express accumulation
As you will notice probably from the following question, I came from computer science, where it is common to express recursive operations.
For example:
a = a + b

So, I have the following issue:
I have an operation expressed as:
$$C(i, j) = \sum_{m=0}^{K-1} \sum_{n=0}^{K-1} I(i+m, j+n) \cdot F(m, n)$$
Where dimensions of I are H (rows) by W(columns), and dimensions of F are K(rows) by K(columns).
The window frame of KxK typically performs the operation.
However, I want to express the same operation but perform partial products by going through the rows and columns of I (H and W).
As each multiplication of I*F contributes to the result but needs to be accumulated with the previous result, the formula that comes up to my mind is:
$$C(i, j) = C(i, j) + I(i+m, j+n) \cdot F(m, n)$$

Would that be correct?
Are there such things as "recursive formula" in mathematic notation?


In mathematics, "$=$" means what == does in computer languages, not =. By an abuse of notation, = has come to mean assignment in computing, not equality. But in math, it still means equality.
Also, in computing, there is an underlying sense of time that is absent in mathematics, so variables can have one value now, but another value later. Variables in mathematics have no such sequentialness. They can be given any of wide range of values, but that value is expected to be the same wherever the variable is seen in the same context ("scope" in C.S.).
So your equation $C(i, j) = C(i, j) + I(i+m, j+n) \cdot F(m, n)$ is just false, mathematically - unless either $I(i+m, j+n)$ or $F(m, n)$ is $0$.
The way we handle recursion and sequential values in mathematics is with sequences. Then we can discuss any particular value desired. The concept you are after is expressed mathematically as: for all $0 \le m \le K, 1\le n\le K$,
$$\begin{align}C_{0,0}(i,j) &= I(i,j)\cdot F(0,0)\\
C_{m,n}(i,j) &= C_{m, n-1}(i,j) + I(i + m, j + n)\cdot F(m,n)\\
C_{m,0}(i,j) &= C_{m-1,K}(i,j) + I(i+m,j)\cdot F(m,0)\\
C(i,j) &= C_{K,K}(i,j)\end{align}$$
